# nodeJS : module.exports = {x:f(n)} not working but module.exports.x = f(n) working

Tags: node.js

I'm learning node and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this module.exports:

So I have the following in my test.js file:

```
let test = require('./app');
test.age();
test.testage();
```

I also have this in my app.js file:

```
module.export = {
    age: function(){
    console.log(1);
  }
};

module.exports.testage = function(){
    console.log(1);
}
```

The test.age function is not working ('it says test.age is not a function').
On the other hand test.testage() is working fine.

Can someone explain this occurance?

Comment: use module.exports instead of module.export

Answer (score 2):

```
module.exports = {   // exports instead of export
    age: function(){
    console.log(1);
 }
```

};

```
module.exports.testage = function(){
   console.log(1);
}
```